# pandas ewm and rolling methods to not fill in NAs

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a parameter for ewm and rolling methods to not fill in the NAs?

```
>>> A = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,np.nan,5,6])
>>> A
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    NaN
5    5.0
6    6.0
dtype: float64
>>> eA = A.ewm(alpha = 0.5, ignore_na=True).mean()
>>> eA
0    1.000000
1    1.666667
2    2.428571
3    3.266667
4    3.266667 # I want this to be NA, don't fill in
5    4.161290
6    5.095238
dtype: float64
```

Of course this is easily solved by

```
eA[A.isnull()] = np.nan
```

But this takes some unnecessary running time, and the need to think of a variable name for every rolling function is bothersome when you have more than a few.

Comment: An alternative is to filter out the `NaN` in the first instance and then call `combine_first`: `eA = A[A.notnull()].ewm(alpha = 0.5, ignore_na=True).mean()
eA.combine_first(A)` will give you the desired result

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the `combine_first` function. It will be useful. Here the problem is that if you call `ewm(min_periods=...)`, this will fill the warmup NAs.

Comment: The problem here is that what you're after doesn't exist within `ewm` so you can either just set to `NaN` as you've proposed, drop the `NaN` values prior to calling `ewm` and then you have many options such as `combine_first` or `reindex` and pass the index of your orig df which will re-insert the `NaN` values back into the `ewm` result

Comment: I'm OK to take "currently do not exist" as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this currently isn't supported in [`ewm`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html#pandas.Series.ewm), you'd have to overwrite with `NaN` using your proposed method or filter our the `NaN` rows so that `ewm` produces a `Series` preserving the original index, you can then either use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to re-insert the `NaN` rows:

```
In [32]:
A = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,np.nan,5,6])
eA = A[A.notnull()].ewm(alpha = 0.5, ignore_na=True).mean()
eA.combine_first(A)

Out[32]:
0    1.000000
1    1.666667
2    2.428571
3    3.266667
4         NaN
5    4.161290
6    5.095238
dtype: float64

In [33]:
eA.reindex(A.index)

Out[33]:
0    1.000000
1    1.666667
2    2.428571
3    3.266667
4         NaN
5    4.161290
6    5.095238
dtype: float64
```

Comment: `A[A.notnull()].ewm(...).mean().reindex(A.index)` would be a nice one-liner workaround to save me from generating variable names :)

Comment: Sure that'd work, personally I try to avoid chaining just for clarity